# Outlook desktop 2016 - Appointment Item.to.setAsync() not working

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am working on a outlook add-in and the desktop version of outlook is once again thwarting my plans.
I'm trying to set the attendees in an appointment. That works fine on the web version but on the desktop version, there is no 'attendees' field only a 'to' field and when i use the

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.requiredAttendees.setAsync(attendees, callback)
```

with the attendees (being an array of emails), the behaviour on desktop is that it adds the attendees to the 'to' field instead of setting it which is problematic when i want to reset the 'to' field through the add-in using the setAsync() method. I then tried to modify the 'to' field using the

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.to.setAsync(attendees, callback)
```

With hopes that it would bypass the problem but it seems that the mailbox.item does not have a field named 'to'.

Is this a bug of some sort or is this behaviour intended in which case I am doomed to suffer :(

Environment setup :
Microsoft Outlook 2016 (16.0.5182.1000) //
Exchange 2016 (build version 15.1.2375.7) on-premise

Comment: I'd suggest posting that to the `OfficeJS` repo at github as an issue.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this issue using Outlook 16.0.5197.1000. Can you try Windows update to ensure that you don't have any missing updates? If your add-in's manifest is public, can you share a link to it so that I could try it out locally?